# Mysql - group by and weighted avg in the same row

Tags: mysql

I have a bit of a problem formulating a query in MySQL.

This is what i have in my database

```
Part #    Desc.  Tracking #   EquivalentKey  Qty    PriceEach
A         aa      123         1               2     .30
B         dd      342         1               10    1.40
C         dfd     2343        2               100   3
D         awe     43455       3               90    6
E         dffd    5643        2               10    5
```

So given this data, this is my desired output

```
Part#      Equivalent Part # 1       Total Qty    Weighted Avg Price
A          B                         12           1.358
```

... and so on

Basiclly i want to group by PN and then by Equivalent PN, and show all PNs in the same row, add the tot
Any idea how to do this ? i did try the Group By function but it gives me another row for equivalent PN

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What makes part A so special? Why not show part B in column `Part#`?

Comment: that could be done as well, i do not care what the order is, they are both alternative number

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this:

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Part) AS Parts
  , EquivalentKey
  , SUM(Qty) AS Total_Qty
  , SUM(Qty * PriceEach) / SUM(Qty)
        AS Weighted_Avg_Price
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY 
    EquivalentKey ;
```

Comment: Thank you but my sql version does not support Group_Concat

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is supported since MySQL 4.1 - about time for an upgrade!

Comment: @ypercube Don't you want to use `/ sum(qty)` and not `/count(*)`?

Comment: Hi AndreKR, unfourtunatly, i am not the database admin, and i am not even sure if they can do the upgrade, for now, this is what i have to work with

Comment: @user1943748 It would be good if you edited your answer and tagged with the MySQL version you are using. If you are still on 4.0, oh well ...

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have `GROUP_CONCAT()` then you can use the following which assumes only two part no's per EquivalentKey:

```
select min(partno) PartNo, 
  max(partno) EquivalentPartNo,
  TotalQty,
  WeighedAvgPrice
from yourtable t1
left join
(
  select EquivalentKey,
    sum(qty) TotalQty, 
    sum(qty * priceeach) / sum(qty) WeighedAvgPrice
  from yourtable
  group by EquivalentKey
) src
  on t1.EquivalentKey = src.EquivalentKey
group by TotalQty, WeighedAvgPrice;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f391a/13)

Or without the subquery:

```
select min(partno) PartNo, 
  max(partno) EquivalentPartNo,
  sum(qty) TotalQty,
  sum(qty * priceeach) / sum(qty) WeighedAvgPrice
from yourtable t1
group by EquivalentKey;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f391a/15)

If you have access to `GROUP_CONCAT()` then you will use:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(partno) PartNo, 
  sum(qty) TotalQty,
  sum(qty * priceeach) / sum(qty) WeighedAvgPrice
from yourtable t1
group by EquivalentKey;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f391a/16)

Comment: Thank you Bluefeet but the number of equivalent part number has no restriction , meaning i can having 2, 1 or 23 equivalent PNs

Comment: @user1943748 what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: i am not sure, but when i got an error the program states mysqld-4.0.27